# How to find the character \u1ec1 in my 300MB XML file?

Tags: python, encoding, xslt-2.0

I have a complicated process that boils down to: I need to find where this one character is that's breaking my XSL transform. Because of the system I'm using, the only info I can get from the XSLT is "it didn't work."

I happen to know that it's getting hung up on the character `\u1ec1`. Reading the XML line by line, how can I determine if that character is in the line, and so purge/correct/ignore the offending record?

My most powerful tool at the moment is Python, so I'm focusing on that.

I've tried:

```
buffer = []
for line in lines:
    for letter in line:
    if (u'\u1ec1') in line:
        buffer.append(line)
```

Then write out the buffer, which should show me every occurrence, and at least get me closer. It failed to encode the character... duh.

I've tried:

```
buffer = []
previous_line = "<start>"
with open(file, 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        for letter in str(line):
            if ord(letter) > 127:
                buffer.append(previous_line)
        previous_line = line
```

Then I can write out the *previous* line without having to worry about encoding errors and whatnot. So far, I get either no results at all, or an encoding error.

This is a relatively insignificant yak that I need to shave on the way to solving a much more important problem. I.e. gross solutions are acceptable, so long as it helps me find the line that's breaking my XSLT. (I have no access to any XSL IDE, except insofar as one can call Notepad++ an XSL IDE).

Comment: Is this python 2? Python 3 unicode support is different (and generally better). What do you mean by "it failed to encode the character"? Post the full stack trace. What is the encoding of the XML file you are reading? You should use that in the `open` (or `codecs.open in python 2). If its utf8, for example, do `open('somefilename', encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: There are a lot of free xslt processers out there that you can use to debug your processes. python's `lxml` is a great tool for brute-force debugging of xpath and also has an xslt processor.

Comment: If you can show me how to get specific errors out of lxml, that'd be great. The tool I'm developing for is in the cloud, so lxml is my primary offline testing platform. I do not have access to any other XSL tools (like Oxygen). So far, lxml will tell me that the transform failed, but not where or why.

Comment: Python 3.5 "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 0; character maps to <undefined>" I don't have the previous stack trace, and this is different from before. I'm not convinced that I can trust the encoding on the XML. It claims to be UTF-8, but specifying UTF-8 in open() still produces encoding errors when trying to read or print().

Comment: I usually create small examples that I test on my local machine. It seems like you have problems with the encoding... your xml and xslt should be written in utf8 or utf16 and should have <xml ...> declarations stating the encoding.

Comment: I'm now trying the grossest solution I might yet have coded... I'm `try: print(letter)` for every letter in the file and appending that letter to another buffer. The `except:` block appends "{error}" instead of the bad char... its' been running for 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes, the XML has an encoding declaration that claims UTF-8. I've tried smaller data sets, but I can't get them to fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163026/discussion-between-matt-and-tdelaney).

Comment: open file with binary mode , convert your search text to bytes and find.  Ignore system,file,shell encodings(Don't forget: system(base) work without encodings(only 255 char)).